# splice() for anonymous memory — any performance benefits?

Tags: linux, system-calls, splice

According to the manpage of `splice` it allows you to

> move data between two file descriptors without copying between kernel address space and user address space.

Does that imply there are any performance benefits to be had if that would be used with anonymous memory, e.g. a fd returned from `memfd_create`?

Comment: it also depends on the other end. where are you going to transfer from/to ?

Comment: @ZangMingJie — Let's assume the dst is a tcp conn :)

Comment: No, you can't use splice between tcp and memfd, none of these is pipe.

Answer (score 0):

*memory -([vm]splice)-> pipe -(splice)-> socket* can be marginally more efficient than the send or write syscalls since the kernel can just forward pointers and instruct the network card to do DMA from the source instead of copying from userspace buffers under the assumption that they might get modified. But doing so means you promise the kernel not to modify the memory until it has really been drained from the send queue, which can take an arbitrary amount of time after the calls were done. So that's mostly useful for memory that won't be modified. Alternatively you can use the [MSG_ZEROCOPY](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.17/networking/msg_zerocopy.html) option to receive notifications when the page has been finally sent so you can reuse it.

Generally it's simpler to use sendfile where possible